# Simple way of updating an existing map within a List, or appending if it doesn't

Tags: immutable.js

I might be overthinking this, but is there an easy way to merge a change into an existing Map if it exists in a List, otherwise create a new Map at the end of the List?

Something like the following?

```
let mapToUpdateOrInsert = new Map({id: 1})

list.update(list.findIndex((map) => {
  return map.get("id") === mapToUpdateOrInsert.get("id")
}), (update) => {
  return update.merge({something: changed})
})
```